# Getting Error while attempting to create a C# xUnit project using Ryder?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, console-application, xunit

I am trying to follow the C# development path on Pluralsight to begin learning C#. I am at the section where we are instructed to create a .Net Core, Unit Test Project of type xUnit. I have followed the instructions on the course to add the new project to my primary solution file. However, when the base code for the xUnit test is populated, Ryder does not seem to detect the xUnit package which I have installed.

I have also made sure to download the latest .NET Framework and .NET core from the Microsoft Website. In addition to completing a full install of Visual Studio, ensuring I have checked each Workload Component needed to develop a .NET Core console application. I will also note that Visual Studio is not detecting the xUnit package either. I did test with and without ReSharper on Visual Studio to test if this was a JetBrains issue. Both times the xUnit package was not detected.

Attached below is the picture of the error I am getting when attempting to download and integrate the package Ryder thinks I am missing. I have also attached a screenshot of my file explorer with the xUnit packages present in the NuGet directory. So unless I am mistaken, I do believe I have the correct xUnit package installed.

This issue may be correlated to an oversight on my part or a simple error that I am not able to locate. However, due to my unfamiliarity with C# development, I am not able to trace the source of the issue. I apologize in advance for the verbose information body for this question. Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Visual Studio to create the test project and then continue with Rider.

Comment: Thank you! This helped, the problem was definitely with creating the test on Rider, it worked perfectly after using visual studio.